# StackDriver Custom Metric for Nodejs event loop latency

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to construct a custom metric for Google StackDriver that I can use to track nodejs event loop latencies. All the apps are running in Google AppEngine so I am confined to using the monitored resource `global` (at least to my understanding).

Via the nodejs `@google/monitoring` client I have created a metric descriptor looking like this:

```
{
  name: client.projectPath(projectId),
  metricDescriptor: {
    description: 'Nodejs event loop latency',
    displayName: 'Event Loop Latency',
    type: 'custom.googleapis.com/nodejs/eventloop/latency',
    metricKind: 'GAUGE',
    valueType: 'DOUBLE',
    unit: '{ms}',
    labels: [
      {
        key: 'instance_id',
        valueType: 'STRING',
        description: 'The ID of the instance reporting latency (containerId, vmId, etc.)',
      },
    ],
},
```

And writing data to this custom metric like:

```
metric: {
    type: 'custom.googleapis.com/nodejs/eventloop/latency',
    labels: {
      instance_id: instanceId,
    },
  },
  resource: {
    type: 'global',
    labels: {
      project_id: projectId,
    },
  },
  points: [{
    interval: {
      endTime: {
        seconds: item.at,
      },
    },
    value: {
      doubleValue: item.value,
    },
  }],
};
```

I thought all was good while writing my tests, until I tried changing my `instance_id` to write data that was in an overlapping timespan as another fake instance had already written. Now the monitor client throws the error

`Error: One or more TimeSeries could not be written:
Points must be written in order. One or more of the points specified was older than the most recent stored point.`

Which renders my custom metric VERY useless, only one nodejs process can ever write to this custom metric.

Now my question is, how can I circumvent this? I want to be able to write from all of my nodejs instances running (`x` AppEngine services with `y` instances running).

I was thinking a `type` that is indexed on `nodejs/eventloop/latency/{serviceName}/{serviceVersion}/{instanceId}` but it seems a bit extreme and will quickly bring me towards the quotas on the StackDriver account.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time series data for custom metrics in Stackdriver must be written time in-order as documented in https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource.

A workaround for this is to create a separate time series for every instance writing to the metric by adding a user-defined label for the `instance_id`. You can also add separate labels for `service_name` or `service_version`, if you require it. However, be mindful of the cardinality of the label values. Creating too many timeseries on a single metric can degrade query performance.

More details on what a time series is: See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics-details#intro-time-series.

Comment: Thanks Summit - I was hoping though that the custom metrics had a time-series for each label I created, as this would have solved my problem. I guess I will have to go for creating unique `type`s to track metrics from all the running instances.

Comment: No, you do not need to create a unique metric `type` for each instance. My recommendation was to use a single metric, with `instance_id` as a label. Each unique combination of label values creates a times series. I have clarified this a bit in my answer.